Formio.js get value of select component before and after change
I use formio javascript library to create my forms and I simply need for a dropdown to get its current value and its previous value on change event.
The challenge here is that the dropdown can be in a datagrid and more dropdowns are added when adding row. Like with this simple form configuration:
{ display : 'form'
, components: 
  [ { label              : 'Data Grid'
    , reorder            : false
    , addAnotherPosition : 'bottom'
    , layoutFixed        : false
    , enableRowGroups    : false
    , initEmpty          : false
    , tableView          : false
    , defaultValue       : [ { } ] 
    , key                : 'dataGrid'
    , type               : 'datagrid'
    , input              : true
    , components: 
      [ { label     : 'Test drop down'
        , widget    : 'choicesjs'
        , tableView : true
        , data: 
          { values: 
            [ { label: 'Test 1', value: 'test1' } 
            , { label: 'Test 2', value: 'test2' } 
            , { label: 'Test 3', value: 'test3' } 
            ] 
          } 
        , key       : 'testDropDown'
        , type      : 'select'
        , input     : true
} ] } ] } 


To handle fetching the present and past values of a dropdown in a DataGrid element with the formio, you need to use event listeners for monitoring value change.
To achieve this :

Attach the custom event listeners once the form is ready
Monitor previous and current values by storing in key-value pairs
As dropdowns are added dynamically in the DataGrid, you need to attach event listeners to every new dropdown that gets included

STACKBLITZ LINK


const formConfig = {
    display: 'form',
    components: [{
      label: 'Data Grid',
      reorder: false,
      addAnotherPosition: 'bottom',
      layoutFixed: false,
      enableRowGroups: false,
      initEmpty: false,
      tableView: false,
      defaultValue: [{}],
      key: 'dataGrid',
      type: 'datagrid',
      input: true,
      components: [{
        label: 'Test drop down',
        widget: 'choicesjs',
        tableView: true,
        data: {
          values: [{
              label: 'Test 1',
              value: 'test1'
            },
            {
              label: 'Test 2',
              value: 'test2'
            },
            {
              label: 'Test 3',
              value: 'test3'
            },
          ],
        },
        key: 'testDropDown',
        type: 'select',
        input: true,
      }, ],
    }, ],
  };

  Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), formConfig).then(
    (form) => {
      attachEventListeners(form);
    }
  );

  function attachEventListeners(form) {
    // Store previous and current values for each component
    const componentStates = new Map();

    // Function to handle the change event for dropdowns
    const handleChange = (component, rowIndex) => {
      const path = `${component.path}[${rowIndex}]`;
      let state = componentStates.get(path);
      if (!state) {
        state = {
          previousValue: null,
          currentValue: ''
        };
        componentStates.set(path, state);
      }

      component.on('change', () => {
        state.previousValue = state.currentValue;
        state.currentValue = component.getValue();
        // if (rowIndex)
        console.log(
          `For::${path} Previous Value: ${state.previousValue} , Current Value: ${state.currentValue}`
        );
      });
    };

    // Attach event listeners to existing dropdowns
    form.everyComponent((component) => {
      if (component.component.key === 'testDropDown') {
        handleChange(component, 0);
      }
    });
    // Attach event listeners to new rows in the DataGrid
    form.on('change', (event) => {
      if (
        event.changed &&
        event.changed.component &&
        event.changed.component.key === 'dataGrid'
      ) {
        console.log('fired');
        const dataGridComponent = event.changed.instance;
        dataGridComponent.rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
          if (row.testDropDown.component.key === 'testDropDown') {
            handleChange(row.testDropDown, rowIndex);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
<script src="https://cdn.form.io/formiojs/formio.full.min.js"></script>


<div id="formio"></div>




Based on your requirements, I have roughly added some listeners and buttons to simulate the process of adding form options.

To obtain its current value and change the previous events in the event
The "value" section is monitored by listening to change, where the value is obtained through index. (form-renderer#log-change-events)
The dynamic acquisition option uses triggerRedraw to force a re rendering to update the form.(component-settings#redraw-on)

a demo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form.io Dropdown Tracking</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.form.io/formiojs/formio.full.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="formio"></div>
    <script>
      const formDefinition = {
        display: "form",
        components: [
          {
            label: "Data Grid",
            reorder: false,
            addAnotherPosition: "bottom",
            layoutFixed: false,
            enableRowGroups: false,
            initEmpty: false,
            tableView: false,
            defaultValue: [{}],
            key: "dataGrid",
            type: "datagrid",
            input: true,
            components: [
              {
                label: "Test drop down",
                widget: "choicesjs",
                tableView: true,
                data: {
                  values: [
                    { label: "Test 1", value: "test1" },
                    { label: "Test 2", value: "test2" },
                    { label: "Test 3", value: "test3" },
                  ],
                },
                key: "testDropDown",
                type: "select",
                input: true,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
      const previousValues = {};

      Formio.createForm(document.getElementById("formio"), formDefinition).then(
        (form) => {
          function addValuesToDropdown(newValues) {
            const dataGrid = form.getComponent("dataGrid");
            dataGrid.components.forEach((row) => {
              const dropdown = row.getComponent("testDropDown");
              dropdown.component.data.values.push(...newValues);
              dropdown.triggerRedraw();
            });
          }

          const newDropdownValues = [
            { label: "Test 4", value: "test4" },
            { label: "Test 5", value: "test5" },
          ];
          addValuesToDropdown(newDropdownValues);

          form.on("change", (event) => {
            if (
              event.changed &&
              event.changed.component &&
              event.changed.component.key === "testDropDown"
            ) {
              const dataGridIndex = event.instance.component.id;
              const currentValue = event.changed.value;
              const previousValue = previousValues[dataGridIndex] || null;

              console.log(
                `Previous value: ${previousValue}, Current value: ${currentValue}`
              );

              previousValues[dataGridIndex] = currentValue;
            }
          });
        }
      );
    </script>
    <style>

      .choices__list.choices__list--dropdown{
        position: static !important;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>


